# A Bit More Than Positive Definite Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A positive definite (take as implying symmetric) square matrix $A$ satisfies for all $x$

$$
0< \langle A x ,x \rangle.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$

it turns out that this $\implies$ its eigenvalues are positive. $\textbf{Q1:}$ Does the reverse implication hold?

Consider now a different condition for $A$ which I will call elliptic, $A$ is elliptic if for all $x$ and some $c>0$.

$$
c|x|^2\leq \langle A x ,x \rangle.~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
$$

$\textbf{Q2:}$ how different is $(1)$ to $(2)$ what extra properties do we need of $A$ to get $(2)$ from $(1)$?

Comment: $A$ is elliptic iff the lowest eigenvalue of $\frac{A+A^T}{2}$ is greater than $c$.

Comment: @Mindlack that is great news for me :) Do you have a reference to that result? or can you give a proof? I am VERY thankful for your answer iv'e been struggling with this for ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $A'=\frac{A+A^T}{2}$. Then $A'$ is symmetric and $A-A'$ is skew-symmetric; thus $\langle x,\,Ax\rangle = \langle x,\,A'x\rangle$ for any real vector $x$.

Now, $A'$ is diagonal is some orthonormal basis, which implies that $\{\langle x,\,Ax\rangle,\,\|x\|=1\}$ is exactly the interval between the lowest and the highest eigenvalue of $A'$, hence the conclusion.

Comment: What does it mean to be diagonal "in some basis"

Comment: It means that the (natural) endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by $A'$ has an orthonormal basis made with eigenvectors.

Comment: and it needs to be symmetric to make this work?

Comment: Do you know where i could read more about this, Im finding it hard going off what you wrote.

Comment: The important thing is that $A’$ is diagonal in some orthonormal basis (this is equivalent to $A’$ being symmetric – any non-beginner linear algebra textbook mentioning Euclidean spaces should discuss this). What this means is that there are pairwise orthogonal vectors $u_1,\dots,u_n$ with norm one and scalars $\lambda_1 \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_n$ such that $A’u_i=\lambda_i u_i$. Now, if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, write $x_i=\langle x,\, u_i \rangle$, then $x=\sum_{i=1}^n{x_iu_i}$, $\|x\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}$, and $\langle x,\, Ax\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n{\lambda_i x_i^2} \geq \lambda_1 \|x\|^2$.

Comment: Ah wait I think I got it : symmetric $\implies$ diagonizable $\implies$ the eigenvectors form a basis. The rest is done via your agrument.

Answer (score 2):

Caution: $A$ is positive definite , iff

$$(1) \quad 0< \langle A x ,x \rangle$$

for all $x \ne 0.$

$Q2:$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent:

It is clear that $(2)$ implies $(1)$.

Now supoose that $(1)$ holds. The function $f(x):=\langle A x ,x \rangle$ is continuous and $K:=\{x \in \mathbb R^n: ||x||=1\}$ is compact. Hence there is $c>0$ such that $f(x) \ge c$ for all $x \in K.$ This gives $(2)$

Comment: does any of this require the symmetry of $A$?

Comment: It seems like no. Even though it is usually included in the definition of positive definite...